# Restore RAID1 after motherboard change

Tags: motherboard, raid-1

I have a RAID1 (2 drives, mirror) on an Advantech AIMB-782QG2-00A1E motherboard (Intel Rapid Storage Technology).

The motherboard recently died so I have ordered a new one (same model).

Do I need to make any special configuration in the BIOS in order to get back the RAID1? or it will work just installing the new motherboard and pluggin in the SATA drives?

Thanks in advance!